# Prove or disprove that the product $PVPVP$ is nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be the inverse of a positive definite M-matrix and $V\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be any diagonal matrix. Prove (or disprove) that $PVPVP$ is nonnegative.

I know of the following.

$P=P^T \succ 0$. $P$ is also nonnegative. Moreover, $p_{jk}p_{ii} \ge p_{ji}p_{ik}$ for any $i,j,k$.

I can verify that the statement is true for $n=2$, but I don't know how to work with $n$ large. Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185629/product-pvpvp-is-nonnegative, without notice to either site.

Comment: My apologies. I'll be more careful next time.